# How to fix 'Int' is not convertible to 'Class'

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I am new to Swift, and I'm migrating my app from Java. In my Swift project I have a Book class with a function named toBook:

```
class Book {
    func toBook(_ resource: Int) -> Int {
        return (resource & 0xFF0000) >> 16
    }
}
```

When I try calling the `toBook` function in another class, I get the error: `Int is not convertible to Book`

```
class Version {
    func reference(resource: Int) -> String {
        var bookId = Book.toBook(resource) //error:'Int' is not convertible to 'Book'
        return reference(bookId);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: you need to declare your method as static `static func toBook(_ resource: Int) -> Int {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving your goal. The simplest one would be initializing the `Book` class in your `func reference` method:

```swift
class Version {
    func reference(resource: Int) -> String {
        let bookId = Book().toBook(resource) // notice the `()` after Book
        return reference(bookId);
    }

    // or even more simplified
    func reference(resource: Int) -> String {
        reference(Book().toBook(resource)) // compatible with Swift 5+
    }
}
```

As Leo Tabus suggests it is also valid to change the `toBook` method into a static on, so you won't need to initialize the book object in the first place. But then I would recommend changing the book class into an enum (but only and I mean absolutely ONLY if you are exclusively using static methods or properties):

```swift
enum Book {
    static func toBook(_ resource: Int) -> Int {
        return (resource & 0xFF0000) >> 16
    }
}
```

A bit of a long shot but as far as I'm concerned clean code wise I would suggest using the class approach with an extension on `Book` since you are trying to map values there that are probably not party of real Book implementation:

```swift
class Book {
    // properties and methods and whatnot you need for this class
}

extension Book {
    func toBook(_ resource: Int) -> Int {
        return (resource & 0xFF0000) >> 16
    }
}
```

Remember to initialize the book object first. But again that's more or less taste.

Comment: I have found initializing the class to be the most "universal" solution. Thanks.